# Prove that $\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:x<y\}$ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

Prove that $\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:x<y\}$ is connected.

Looking at the graph it is clear but how do I proof it theoretically. Thank you

Comment: Always go back to the definition. To be disconnected means that you can write it as a union of two non-empty disjoint open sets. Can you do that here?

Comment: from graphically not possible

Comment: Right, but we don't want to use the graph in the proof. It looks like someone has gone and given an answer, but it uses the notion of path connectedness. I say you should still try this proof by contradiction and see if you can solve it that way.

Comment: @Valborg, Can you give me an example of continuous function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow M$

Answer (score 3):

If $(x,y)$ belongs to your set and $t\in[0,1]$, then every point of the form $\bigl((1-t)x,t+(1-t)y\bigr)$ also does, because$$t+(1-t)y-(1-t)x=t+(1-t)(y-x)>0.$$Therefore, your set is path connected, because the map\begin{array}{rccc}\gamma\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\middle|\,y>x\right\}\\&t&\mapsto&\bigl((1-t)x,t+(1-t)y\bigr)\end{array}is a path from $(0,1)$ to $(x,y)$. Since it is path-connected, it is connected.

Comment: very nice approach..

Comment: If I take the  map $t:\rightarrow ((1-t)x ,(1-t)y)$, Is there any problem?

Comment: @1256 What's the domain of your map? $[0,1]$? Then there's a problem, because $0$ is not mapped into your set.

Comment: got it................

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the rotation to $\pi/4$ clockwise, then $(x,y)\rightarrow A(x,y)$ is homeomorphism from $S$ to the upper half plane $M:=\{(x,y): y>0\}$.

It suffices to prove that $M$ is path-connected. But this is clear because any point in the line segment of any two points of $M$ must have strictly positive $y$-coordinate. Think of the convexity.